# Deleting the through association record when deassociating

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 6.1 app, I have a standard `has_many through` association

```rb
class Enrollment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :topic
  belongs_to :job_description, optional: true
end

class Topic < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :job_descriptions, through: :enrollments
end

class JobDescription < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :topics, through: :enrollments
end
```

Now, when updating a topic (removing a job description)

```
@topic.job_descriptions = [...]
@topic.save
```

The `topic_id` in the `enrollments` having the `job_description_id` no longer associated with the topic is set to `NULL`.
Is there a way to delete the row instead?

Answer (score 1):

try changing

```rb
    has_many :job_descriptions, through: :enrollments
```

to

```rb
    has_many :job_descriptions, through: :enrollments, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: I have tried it, but the `enrollments` aren't deleted. I supposed because the `job descriptions` aren't deleted but "simply" deassociated.

Comment: That's strange. It worked here, the default was already deleting and was only setting null if i set `dependent: :nullify` on `has_many :job_descriptions`

Comment: Tried to replicate the problem, without adding any `dependent`. [It deleted the enrollment row](https://imgur.com/qIzaXem)